# Unable to run executable without explicity adding .exe after the name in windows vista

Tags: path, windows-vista, command, cmd, exe

In my windows vista command prompt I am unable to run an executable like ipconfig or ruby without explicitly adding the .exe extension after. For example:

ipconfig.exe works but ipconfig does not

My path seems to be fine, it contains C:\windows\system32, and my PATHEXT includes the .EXE extension. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

where's the comment box?
anyways, was it always like this or did this just started to happen all of sudden?